# Printer Status: "Paused; Rejecting Jobs"

Tags: linux, printing, canon

I've got a Canon D550 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running XFCE 4.14. Whenever I try to print something, it says that the printer status is "Paused; Rejecting Jobs"

[image: picture of what the dialogue box looks like.]

I've installed the printer drivers, and the CUPS service is started. The strange thing is that I can't print on Windows either (I have it dual-booted). In Windows, it says "Driver unavailable" even though the driver is installed; if any of that is relevant. I don't really care if it works in Windows, I'm more concerned about it working in Linux.

Canon's "Knowledge Base" is completely useless, and when I called to talk to a person, I was told that the product was only supported through the knowledge base. Nothing in the manual either.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: removing the package cups-browsed fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

To "unpause" or resume a printer on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Open a console and run `system-config-printer`, or search for the `Printers` configurations on your interface;
2. Clear your print jobs pool from stuff you do not want to print anymore;
3. Click `Additional Printer Settings`;
4. Right click your printer and `Enable` it;
5. Wait until it prints the remaining jobs or send a new test;

If it pauses again without printing, it might not be accessible, its configuration is broken or there is some other issue.

> Note that under cups itself this action would be called Resuming the printer.

Cups error logs might be available under `/var/log/cups/error_log`. You should add this information if you want to troubleshoot something else.

Comment: Now the status says "Rejecting Jobs". `var/log/cups/error_log` is empty, there is nothing in the file. There is a `error_log.1` file that says the following:

>E [06/Jun/2020:16:42:25 -0500] [Client 8] Returning IPP server-error-not-accepting-jobs >for Create-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/D500-Series) from localhost.
>E [06/Jun/2020:16:52:43 -0500] [Client 8] Returning IPP server-error-not-accepting-jobs >for Create-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/D500-Series) from localhost.

Comment: `error_log.1` is a file that has been rotated, so it may reflect an error from the past instead of the current state (as the current log is empty). Still, your printer seems to be responding but not accepting jobs. I suggest you to review your configurations and make sure that the printer is actually working. As it doesn't also work on other OS there can be an issue on the printer itself.